# Need a regex for checking "2 alphabets and 4 numeric" only in a string

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation

I need your help to write a regex for validating a string that should follow below rule.

"2 Alphabet and 4 Numeric. And it can be a mixed string"

Eg: 11a1a1 or 1a11a1..etc

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not enough information and unclear what you are asking, also getting your friends to upvote and mark your question as favourite is bad form

Comment: I dont think that its unclear.Anybody can simply understand the same.

Comment: @wp78de Let me check.

Comment: What does *it can be a mixed string* mean?

Comment: @dawg from the example  you can see.Any format or any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
^(?=.*\d.*?\d.*?\d.*?\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

Since the question does not specify how long such a string could be, any length is accepted as long as the basic rule is fulfilled.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/88IazW/1/)

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*\d.*?\d.*?\d.*?\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z]).+$/gm;
const str = `aa1111
b1b111
1111aa
11a1a1
1a11a1

aaaa11
bbb111
b1b1b1
b11b1b`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match) => {
        console.log(`Found match: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help.